# how to create side menu in another page not in rootpage (ionic 2)

Tags: ionic2

So this is my case, I already created the login and registration page using ionic 2, my question now is how do I create side menu in my landing page which is not the root page ?? By the way, my root page is the login page.

Comment: Do you want it on only one page?

Comment: yes, I want to create the side menu in the landing page which is not the root page.

Comment: Add your landing page.TS and HTML both.

Comment: what should I add in that page ? I dont understand sir

Comment: edit your question and add html and ts of your landing page.

Comment: Just create your menu in app.component. In which page you want to disable menu, call: `this.menuCtrl.enable(false, "your menu name");`. And if you want to enable the menu, call: `this.menuCtrl.enable(true, "your menu name");`